# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5472 bytes ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error: **Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5472 bytes in /home3/trisoni2/public_html/ohappy/admin/model/extension/module.php on line 32**

I don't know what could be the reason. In PHP I do not really understand, so I give piece of code with a 32 string

```
if ($query->row) {
        if( $query->row['code'] == 'dimastas' ){  
            return $setting =  unserialize($query->row['setting']); /*<--- 32 string*/
        }
        return json_decode($query->row['setting'], true);
    } else {
        return array(); 
    }
}
```

Initially the entries in the database look like this:

```
a:5:{s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:7:"Default";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:6:"layout";s:4377:"[{"cls":"full-col full-slider","bgcolor":"","bgimage":"","fullwidth":"1","parallax":"0","sfxcls":null,"padding":"","margin":"","iposition":null,"iattachment":null,"cols":
```

But after a simple modification, which are provided by the Opencart CMS, the entries in the database are like this:

```
{"status":"1","name":"Default","class":"","layout":"[{\"cls\":\"full-col full-slider\",\"bgcolor\":\"\",\"bgimage\":\"\",\"fullwidth\":\"1\",\"parallax\":\"0\",\"sfxcls\":null,\"padding\":\"\",\"margin\":\"\",\"iposition\":null,\"iattachment\":null,\"cols\":
```

And after all this I get the error:
**Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5472 bytes in /home3/trisoni2/public_html/ohappy/admin/model/extension/module.php on line 32**

In what could be the cause of the error and how to fix it? Please help

Comment: That is wrong....  ***the 2nd  one is JSON*** but **the 1st is a Serialized Object*** You can tell from their signatures...

Comment: Yes.. Here on line 32 you are trying to unserializing json data which is wrong input to function `unserialize`.

Comment: This doesn't look like a phpMyAdmin error message,  am I missing a reason why this is tagged phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems not alright here: ***the 2nd  one is JSON*** but **the 1st is a Serialized Object*** You can tell from their signatures... Notice that **the first one has Prefixes like a:, s:, i:** The **a:** means that everything wrapped up in the Curly Braces following it is an Array. **s** stands for String and **i** for integer. Once you mess with this Structure, you have a Problem.... If your reverted the values to the first one, everything will  work just fine again...

I just convert the Second One (which is JSON) back into a PHP Serialized Data. So now, try replacing the content of the Table-Field with this Value - exactly as it is here:

```
O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:7:"Default";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:6:"layout";a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":11:{s:3:"cls";s:20:"full-col full-slider";s:7:"bgcolor";s:0:"";s:7:"bgimage";s:0:"";s:9:"fullwidth";s:1:"1";s:8:"parallax";s:1:"0";s:6:"sfxcls";N;s:7:"padding";s:0:"";s:6:"margin";s:0:"";s:9:"iposition";N;s:11:"iattachment";N;s:4:"cols";N;}}}
```

**WARNING:** Be sure you have a back-up of the Field somewhere before doing this...although it will  still work... but just in case...

Comment: The fact that I only brought part of the code from the table. I just don't know how to solve this problem why it does not automatically convert to Serialized Object?

Comment: Go back to Pastebin and copy the data there. Please if it works, let me know here....   http://pastebin.com/VMhgA7mZ

Comment: Page is not working

The website is not yet able to process this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
Maybe it is some problems in PHP?